# Are smooth structures determined by their Diff subgroups of Homeo?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $X$ be a topological manifold.

Let $A$ denote the set of smooth structures on $X$, and let $B$ denote the set of subgroups of $\mathrm{Homeo}(X)$.

We have a function $A \rightarrow B$ which associates to a choice of smooth structure the resulting $\mathrm{Diff}$ subgroup of $X$.

In general, is the function $A \rightarrow B$ injective? Thus, is the smooth structure on $X$ determined by the Diff subgroup of $\mathrm{Homeo}(X)$ that it picks out?

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that the isomorphism type of $\operatorname{Diff}(M)$ determines $M$ up to diffeomorphism. This is not exactly your question, but very close.

Comment: @ConnorMalin Thank you, I hadn't heard of this fact; I agree this is very close to my question.